# How to call javascript and write it on html?

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm using this Javascript (API) that has a bunch of function. How do I go about writing it to an HTML file?

so one of the function is "api.ping()" which works fine on powershell, but I cant get it to print that in an HTML file.

So in the script I wrote
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = api.ping();`

and the HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="index.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to put the value returned from the call onto the HTML file.

Comment: Check console for errors

Comment: Should work if api.ping() is not async

Comment: put your `<script>` tag below the `<p>` tag

Comment: @Jithin Sunny please update your question and add the javascript function

Comment: *"onto the HTML file."*: JavaScript within a browser agent does not modify HTML *files*, but in-memory documents.

Comment: `type="index.js"`??? And what about `src`?

Answer (score 5):

I think your index.js file is probably not being included. You'll want to change the  tag line to read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Assuming that index.js is in the same directory as this HTML file.

Comment: This ^^^ -- you have mixed up the src and type properties - index.js needs to be in the src property. If this fixes your problem, show Zach some love by accepting his answer.

Comment: Hey, yea they are in the same directory. And I tried that but didnt work. I'm not too familiar with javascript, is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: @JithinSunny if adding the 'src' attribute didn't fix the problem, I'd then try moving the entire '<script>...</script>' line below your '<p>...</p>' (putting it right before the closing </body> tag)